# Vimeo Gallery - separate title div - to change dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

Hi I am trying to build a gallery of videos on our website, and I have already done 90% of it, using the help from the following topic

[Javascript Vimeo Gallery Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251882/javascript-vimeo-gallery-basics)

```
    <div class="vimeo-container">

            <iframe id="vplayer" 
            src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/.." frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div><!--vimeo-container-->

    <div id="vplayer_title">
    <p>INSERT VIMEO VIDEO TITLE HERE FOR EACH VIDEO<p>
    </div><!--vplayer_title-->


    <div class="bucketthumbs">
    <a class="video-thumbnail" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/.."  video-uri="http://player.vimeo.com/video/..">
        <div class="bucket">
        <img class="gt_orrery" src="images/thumb_1.jpg">
        <div class="title_bucket" id="thumb1_title">
        <p>VIDEO TITLE HERE FOR THIS VIDEO<p>
        </div><!--title_bucket-->
        </div><!--bucket1-->
    </a>


    <a class="video-thumbnail" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/.."  video-uri="http://player.vimeo.com/video/..">
        <div class="bucket">
        <img class="gt_orrery" src="images/thumb_2.jpg">
        <div class="title_bucket" id="thumb2_title">
        <p>VIDEO TITLE HERE FOR THIS VIDEO<p>
        </div><!--title_bucket-->
        </div><!--bucket1-->
    </a>



    <a class="video-thumbnail" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/.."  video-uri="http://player.vimeo.com/video/..">
        <div class="bucket">
        <img class="gt_orrery" src="images/thumb_3.jpg">
        <div class="title_bucket" id="thumb3_title">
        <p>VIDEO TITLE HERE FOR THIS VIDEO<p>
        </div><!--title_bucket-->
        </div><!--bucket1-->
    </a>
    </div><!--bucketthumbs-->
```

This is my html. Using the above topic. I am successfully able to target the thumbnails to change the video in the iframe.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        // Add an event listener to the click event for each of your thumbnails
        $('.video-thumbnail').click(function(e) {

            // changes src of the iframe to the one we stored in the clicked thumbnail
            $('#vplayer').get(0).src = this.getAttribute('video-uri');

            // stops default browser behaviour of loading a new page
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
    });


    </script>
```

But I dont want to use the title that vimeo has on the video. 
Instead I want to display it below the main video and have it change with the video, pulling the titles from vimeo.

I am only a front end developer and my knowledge of javascript and API is extremely limited. I tried to use the same code to get the titles to change too but since that uses src, and attribute i dont think i know how to make it work.

Could someone pls help!? :(

I believe Vimeo has oEmbed that can make it easier. But I cant really understand much of the API, its too basic for me, If its too complicated to solve this issue by using vimeo video titles, a second aleternative would be for me to manually enter the titles on the respect bucket divs, all i need to know is how to dynamically change the title in the main vplayer_title div

Comment: I don't have great advice on how to handle your basic JS tactic, but you are able to easily retrieve video titles using Vimeo's OEmbed endpoint https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Comment: absolutely it seems like the best choice for someone who has a better understanding of the API, I am far too new or rather layman I just cant seem to follow the documentation

Comment: I also tried to look up the api php example on github but for the life of me I cant figure out where am i to change the username or album id etc. and I tried various things but it kept giving me errors. here https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-api-examples/tree/master/simple-api/gallery

Comment: The simple API is completely different from OEmbed. If you want a JSON response, check out https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed#json-example. start with "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=" and just add the video url to the end like the example in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the player's JS API: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Something like this in your thumbnail click event:

```
var player = $f(iframe);

player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.api('getVideoTitle', function(title) {
        // set the title contents here
        $('#vplayer_title').html('<p>' + title + '</p>');
    });
});
```